# C# validating the column values

Tags: c#

using C# how can I verify that the Column contains any of the values from the list

example List: ford, Toyota, BMW, Audi

and the column Make contains any of the values from the list

Comment: List.Contains ?

Comment: How is your data stored? What is "Column"?

Answer (score 0):

If you already have an existing list, you could use the [`Contains()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bhkz42b3(v=vs.110).aspx) method to simply determine if a given item exists:

```
// This assumes that your make is already a string
var isMakeInList = makeList.Contains(make);
```

You could also accomplish this by using the [`Enumerable.Any()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972(v=vs.110).aspx) method exposed in LINQ, which could be useful if you needed to check for any other specific conditions:

```
// This will return true if any element within your list matches the given condition
var isMakeInList = makeList.Any(m => m == make);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean by checking if Column contains one item from the list, I guess you mean if one list contains any item from another list.

```
bool containsCar = Column.Any(x => carsList.Any(y => y == x));
```